# Why diamond sign looks weird in my iPhone?

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a website similar to SO. Moderators have a diamond sign in the end of their name. Bud I don't know why it looks red and weird in my iPhone (on chrome it is fine).

[image]

See? It looks red and huge. Why? And how can I fix it? Noted that SO looks fine in my iPhone:

[image]

Also my styles are the same as SO:

```
.mod-flair {
  color: #07C;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 8px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: You're using an emoji.

Comment: Which character are you using for that diamond?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this `♦`

Comment: @SLaks Well I'm not .. I copy/pasted the same character from SO.

Comment: Use the HTML entity: `&#11045;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Tested .. still the same look. Noted that I've cleared the cache too.

Comment: If this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0qdpzLsb/ - looks correct then it's something in your code (either JS or CSS) which is causing this issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh .. you edited your comment .. now it works well, thank you buddy :-)

Comment: Sorry yeah, I picked the wrong entity originally; `&#9670;`. Glad you got it working. I'll add an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I copy/pasted the same character from SO

This is likely to be the problem, as you're leaving it up to the browser to encode the character. I'd suggest explicitly using a character entity instead. Stack Overflow uses `&#9830;`

```html
&#9830;
```

Comment: Also as a note, that diamond looks (a bit) thin and lengthful in SO, but mine looks like a rotated square. Any idea why?

Comment: Could be caused by line-heights or font-size, or all kinds of text rendering issues. There's plenty of diamond entities if you want to try a different one: https://www.alt-codes.net/diamond-symbols

Comment: Writing the character as a character vs. an entity will not make any difference.  The actual problem is the wrong character.

Comment: @SLaks But my problem resolved by using `&#9830;` instead of `♦`.

Comment: @SLaks Well yeah .. you were right .. It still looks like a big red diamond in some devices *(iPhone 6s)* (you can open [this](https://lamtakam.com/users) with iphone mobile and you will see what I mean exactly). Any idea what should I do?